# How can I solve this "violates not-null constraint"?

Tags: python, django

I alway get this error, even I put default value on the avg_winning_trade:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "avg_winning_trade" of relation "trading_summary" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (43897354-d89b-4014-a607-a0e6ee423b52, 1, 2023-02-05 11:09:56.727199+00, null, 1, 19, 1, 0.00, null, -1.01, -1.01, 0, 0, 0.00, 0%, 0.00).
```

The second null value is avg_winning_trade who cause the error here, I don't know why it is null here

this is my model

```py
class Summary(
  ActivatorModel,
  Model):

  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
  starting_balance = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  total_number_of_trades = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  total_number_of_winning_trades = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  total_number_of_losing_trades = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  total_number_of_be_trade = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  largest_winning_trade = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  largest_losing_trade = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  avg_winning_trade = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  avg_losing_trade = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  total_trade_costs = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  trade_win_rate = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

This is the table

```
 Column             |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
--------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 id                             | uuid                     |           | not null |         | plain    |             |              | 
 status                         | integer                  |           | not null |         | plain    |             |              | 
 activate_date                  | timestamp with time zone |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 deactivate_date                | timestamp with time zone |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 total_number_of_trades         | integer                  |           | not null |         | plain    |             |              | 
 user_id                        | integer                  |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 total_number_of_winning_trades | integer                  |           | not null |         | plain    |             |              | 
 avg_losing_trade               | numeric(10,2)            |           | not null |         | main     |             |              | 
 avg_winning_trade              | numeric(10,2)            |           | not null |         | main     |             |              | 
 largest_losing_trade           | numeric(10,2)            |           | not null |         | main     |             |              | 
 largest_winning_trade          | numeric(10,2)            |           | not null |         | main     |             |              | 
 total_number_of_be_trade       | integer                  |           | not null |         | plain    |             |              | 
 total_number_of_losing_trades  | integer                  |           | not null |         | plain    |             |              | 
 total_trade_costs              | numeric(10,2)            |           | not null |         | main     |             |              | 
 trade_win_rate                 | character varying(10)    |           | not null |         | extended |             |              | 
 starting_balance               | numeric(10,2)            |           | not null |         | main     |             |              |
```

Answer (score 0):

avg_winning_trade field value should not be null.

Comment: Yes, I know but, the problem is why it is null. Its value is similar to the avg_losing_trade and It's not null

Answer (score 0):

my Bad, I think I figured it myself. avg_winning_trade has 0 value by default but, In my testing I was sending null value to It. Since there was not winning trade.